# Optimize translate animation on element with multiple child nodes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gsap

I'm trying to optimize transition of "infinity list" animation. The problem is that this is just a demo in the real app there are many things popping from each "pin". But the main performance issue is from the translateX animation. For Each node added the transition gets laggy, i do not understand why translating the parent node is affected by the number of child nodes in it. Is there any performance optimization I can make to make things smoother

```
<template>
      <div
        v-if="rects"
        ref="container"
        class="container"
        :style="`transform: translate3d(${translateX}px, 0, 0)`"
      >
        <div v-for="index in rects" :key="index" class="rect">
          <div class="pin"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import gsap from "gsap";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      props: {
        rectNumber: {
          type: Number,
          default: 10000
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          rects: null,
          translateX: 0
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        this.rects = this.rectNumber;
        setInterval(() => {
          this.tick();
        }, 300);
      },
      methods: {
        tick() {
          gsap.to(this, {
            translateX: this.translateX - 20,
            duration: 0.3,
            ease: "none"
          });
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Demo Link: https://rz6p6.csb.app/

Editor Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-cori-rz6p6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

> For Each node added the transition gets laggy, i do not understand why translating the parent node is affected by the number of child nodes in it.

Why *wouldn't* it affect the performance? You're rendering 10,000 elements! That's a lot of work for the browser to do.

The best improvement of performance is if you reduce the number of rects. Why do you need so many anyway? What's the goal? You only need a couple of more rects than can show on the page. Calculate what that number should be and only use that many ticks. Or better yet, use a repeating background image so you only need one element.

Comment: you mean a virtual scroll implementation ? Anyway each rect represents request and the whole thing must always keep the old states, so yeah they will possibly exceed even 5k

Comment: No, what about my answer suggested anything about virtual scroll? There's no reason why you should load 5k states at any point. Notice what sites like Facebook and Twitter do when you scroll through the feed - they remove old elements and add new ones in the infinite scroll. The browser can't handle thousands of DOM elements performantly.